# XAML detect if listview item is focused or not

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xbox-one

I am trying to detect which item in a listview is focused, but I am not getting the events detected. I am developing for Xbox One UWP, so I cannot use mouse or keyboard events, only focus can be used.

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" GotFocus="StackPanel_GotFocus" >
            <StackPanel Name="Imagestack" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="144" Width="256" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

```cs
private void StackPanel_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Image focus");
    Image img = sender as Image;
    Bgimage.Source = img.Source;
}
```

Comment: Your sender is not Image. Its Stackpanel. You have to walk your way down to the Image within the StackPanel

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake. But the event is not getting detecting, i dont get the log.

Comment: I don't think a stackpanel **can** get focus. What would it even do with it?

Comment: *Controls* are focusable, and *StackPanel* derives from *Panel* class.

Comment: What do you want to achieve - what do you mean by focused? Does it mean selected? If so then why not to use *SelectionChanged* event of ListView? If by focus you mean highlighting the element before selsection, then maybe you can use *Pointer* events for that - for example subscribe to *StackPanel's* *PointerEntered* (lost/canceled) events depending on your needs.

Comment: I am developing for xboxone platform and all navigation are based on focus. That is why i am not using select item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register to the `ListView.GotFocus` event.

The `OriginalSource` from the event parameter will be the `ListViewItem` which has received the focus. You can then retrieve the item content using `ListViewItem.Content`.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="list" GotFocus="list_GotFocus">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>...</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void list_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var focusedItem = (e.OriginalSource as ListViewItem)?.Content; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I completed by   MyListItem focusedItem = (MyListItem)(e.OriginalSource as ListViewItem)?.Content;
            Debug.WriteLine("focusedItem " + focusedItem.Title);
            Debug.WriteLine("focusedItem " + focusedItem.index);
            var temp = focusedItem.Image;
            Bgimage.Source = (ImageSource)temp;

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to get focus state to get data from the clicked ListViewItem, the `ItemClick` event of the `ListView` may be what you're looking for:

```
<ListView x:Name="LV_Items"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="LV_Items_ItemClick"
          >
</ListView>

private void LV_Items_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Get instance of the model in the clicked ListViewItem
    MyModel myModel = (MyModel)e.ClickedItem;

    Image img = myModel.Image;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use click because i need focus (xbox one platform - navigation). Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried it on real xbox? I haven't got a chance but I doubt that you have to track the focus to get the selected item..

Comment: Yeah i tried i Xbox and used focus to track the navigation